# How to add a variable or function value to an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am trying to pass the value of LibIds($output); which outputs as "1000001,1000002" to the below code

I'd like:

```
 function LibIds($output)
{
$rows = get_field('library_add_ids');
    if($rows)
    {
        ob_start();
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
        echo $row['id'].',';
        }
        $output = ob_get_clean();

        echo rtrim($output, ',');
    }
}
 $res = $api->query('bibs', array(
   'id' => '1000001,1000002', 
   'fields' => 'id,updatedDate,createdDate,deletedDate,deleted,suppressed,available,lang,title,author,materialType,bibLevel,publishYear,catalogDate,country,orders,normTitle,normAuthor,locations,fixedFields,varFields'
 ));
```

...which works... to be

```
    function LibIds($output)
{
$rows = get_field('library_add_ids');
    if($rows)
    {
        ob_start();
        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
        echo $row['id'].',';
        }
        $output = ob_get_clean();

        echo rtrim($output, ',');
    }
}

$res = $api->query('bibs', array(
   'id' => 'LibIds($output);', 
   'fields' => 'id,updatedDate,createdDate,deletedDate,deleted,suppressed,available,lang,title,author,materialType,bibLevel,publishYear,catalogDate,country,orders,normTitle,normAuthor,locations,fixedFields,varFields'
 ));
```

... the 3rd last line is the issue  `'id' => '1000001,1000002',` not sure if parsing is required or whats the best way. PHP Newbie. 
Thanks

Comment: `'id' => 'LibIds($output);',` should be `'id' => LibIds($output);,` (notice the absence of quote marks)

Comment: `ob_start()`? In a MVC framework?

Comment: Thanks William ... I experimented with what you advised but the value just doesn't populate across for some reason. Playing around with a library API so curious what I can get it to do.

Comment: also tried: `function LibIds($output)
{
$rows = get_field('library_add_ids');
$resultstr = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $resultstr[] = $row['id'];
}
echo implode(",",$resultstr);
}`

Comment: resolved with: `$rows = get_field('library_add_ids');
$resultstr = array();
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $resultstr[] = $row['id'];
}
$ids = implode(",",$resultstr);
$res = $api->query('bibs', array(
   'id' => $ids,
   'fields' => 'id,updatedDate,createdDate,deletedDate,deleted,suppressed,available,lang,title,author,materialType,bibLevel,publishYear,catalogDate,country,orders,normTitle,normAuthor,locations,fixedFields,varFields'
 ));`